# What is your alternative name for ID variable in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, naming-conventions

Since "id" is a keyword in Objective-C what alternative name do you use for ID variable (e.g. PK field)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think it should be noted that the compiler can distinguish between `id` in the type specifier position and `id` in the variable name position. That is,

```
NSUInteger id;
id = 10;
```

will compile just fine (as, indeed, will `id id; id = [NSNumber numberWithInt:10];`). (You could also uppercase it: `ID`.) That said, those are all horrible ideas. Don't use them. Forget I even said that.

The style in Cocoa programming is to tend towards verbosity, so (as all the earlier answers have suggested) the best practice is probably to write it all out: `identifier` or `dinglehopferID`.

Comment: heh, I even haven't tried to name it "id" and compile :) thank you for the note! of course I am going to stick to "identifier"

Answer (score 3):

`identifier`, or something more specific like `userID`.

Answer (score 0):

It often depends on context. Simply, `identifier` if I'm not feeling particularly creative.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use either 'identifier' — if there's really no better alternative — or something domain specific like 'programmeID' which sort of says 'this is the primary key, but only with respect to this domain'.

It's actually quite rare that you have to think in terms of primary keys within Cocoa. Core Data preserves object graphs without any nomination of primary keys, `NSPredicate`s don't give inherently any additional weight to a field that happens to be unique per object and `NSDictionary`s tend to be built in an adhoc fashion.

Answer (score 0):

I almost use 'guid' `NSString *guid`  `NSNumber *guid`.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier

Answer (score 0):

Using id is a bad idea for me. I almost use 'uid' or 'cid' for Users and Clients respectively. I use the first letter of the model name to avoid the reserved word.