# NSJSONSerialization for an object with an id attribute

Tags: objective-c

So I'm trying to do a GET request that returns some Json. The json that gets returned from this request has an id attribute, so the class that I use NSJSONSerialization to parse the json should have an id attribute.  Since id is reserved in objective-c, I can't include it as an attribute in my class.  Basically, my question boils down to what should I do to make sure the id attribute gets parsed correctly into an object of my class.

Comment: Can you paste the JSON into your question for clarity's sake please? I think I know what you're saying but I'd like to confirm.

Comment: `id` is not illegal as an identifier (and neither is `ID`), but it's better to use a more specific name anyways. See [What is your alternative name for ID variable in Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505518/what-is-your-alternative-name-for-id-variable-in-objective-c). That said, you should be able to name your property whatever you want. Why does it have to exactly match the JSON key?

Comment: There's no requirement that you place JSON object elements in variables named the same as the element key.  I suppose a few folks use some sort of automated scheme to assign JSON object elements to Objective-C object properties, but it's far from "usual" (unlike Java where folks don't seem to know how to do anything else).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `id` is a reserved keyword (although, as Josh points out, you *could* use it as a variable name, he's quite right that's a bad idea), but it can still be used as a key in a `NSDictionary`. For example, if your JSON looks like:

```
{ "id" : "23432423", "name" : "Jason Boggess" }
```

You can then parse it as follows:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"%s: JSONObjectWithData error: %@", __FUNCTION__, error);
    return;
}
NSString *identifier = dictionary[@"id"];
NSString *name = dictionary[@"name"];
```

Comment: It's worth clarifying that "i. e. you can write the **string** `@"id"` and that won't conflict with the type name."

Comment: `id id; id = [[NSObject alloc] init];` isn't illegal anyways, though it's a terrible idea.

Comment: Yes, it's really just a bit of trivia, @Rob; if it has any relevance to real code I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 3):

If you passed

```
{
    id: 123,
    name: "Chris"
}
```

to `NSJSONSerialization` as an `NSData` object you would get an `NSDictionary` with two keys that are `NSString`'s with the value `@"id"` and `@"name"`, at that point you can take the value from the `id` key and pass it to an attribute on your Objective-C model that is named something other than `id`. An example being `recordId`