# Finding a particular instance in an array by a property

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray

I have an array containing various instances of `MyClass`, which has four properties: `int id`, `int valueA`, `int valueB`, and `int valueC`. On occasion, I need to modify a property for a specific instance (for this example let's say it is the one with `id` equal to `5`).

Currently I do it like this:

```
MyClass *myClass = [[MyClass alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i < [myMutableArray count]; i++)
{
    myClass = [myMutableArray objectAtIndex:i];

    if(myClass.id == 5)
    {
        myClass.valueA = 100;
        myClass.valueB = 200;
        myClass.valueC = 300;
        [myMutableArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject: myClass];
    }
}
```

Is there a better (I am hesitant to say more efficient) way of doing this?

Comment: Don't name a variable id - it's a reserved keyword

Comment: Good point. Was just using it for this example. Was too lazy to type out 'identification'.

Comment: See [NJSONSerialization for an object with an "id" attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17634584) for more on that point. /cc @Mario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straightforward, though wordy, way to get a particular member of the array by any criteria at all is to use `indexOfObjectPassingTest:` combined with `objectAtIndex:`

```
MyClass * theInstanceIWant;
theInstanceIWant = [myArray objectAtIndex:[dates indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL (id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                                                        return ([obj id] == 5);
                    }];

theInstanceIWant.valueA = 100;
theInstanceIWant.valueB = 200;
theInstanceIWant.valueC = 300;
```

There's no need to use `replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:` -- the name `theInstanceIWant` refers to the actual object in the array, and you can change its properties while it's still in the array.

---

(This is made more pleasant with a category method on `NSArray`.)

```
- (id)WSSObjectPassingTest:(BOOL (^)(id obj, NSInteger idx, BOOL *stop))test
{
    NSUInteger testedIndex = [self indexOfObjectPassingTest:test];
    return [self objectAtIndex:testedIndex];
}
```

Comment: Your code is kinda out of my league... According to the Apple Docs. this "Returns the index of the first object in the array that passes a test in a given Block". I kinda get that part but how would I replace/update the class instance, once the properties have been changed, in my mutable array using the above code?

Comment: Maybe I am not seeing the obvious here. I understand the part of update the class properties using your code. But how do I update the class instance in my array afterwards? In my example i use the [myMutableArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject: myClass] command. How do I do it with your code?

Comment: You don't need to. You have two references to the same object, one via the array, and one via the name `theInstanceIWant`. Imagine you opened a text file in TextEdit, changed some stuff, and then opened the file in BBEdit -- you still only have one file, and the changes are viewable via both references.

Comment: I am trying to implement your code... what is the 'dates' stand for? For the second code snippet, I am getting an error for the line starting with NSUInteger and the line starting with return - "No visible interface for (my class name) declares the selector 'indexOfObjectPassingTest'".

Comment: `dates` is your array of date objects. The second snippet is for a category method on `NSArray`, not for your class.

Comment: It works beautifully.. not sure how it works right now, but it works. Now to sift through and modify my loops in 40,000 lines of code. BTW - really cool knot!

Answer (score 3):

If you know that there is only 1 instance with an `id` of 5, just add a `break;` at the end of the `if` statement after you have made your updates. This will terminate the loop iteration and is probably the most efficient.

You shouldn't worry too much about runtime performance without profiling.

To write less code, you can write the `for` as:

```
for (MyClass *myClass in myMutableArray) {
```

You may want to change away from using an array for your storage if you need to access individual items often anyway.

Also, don't do:

```
MyClass *myClass = [[MyClass alloc] init];
```

Because you're needlessly creating an instance that you never use and just gets thrown away.

Comment: Very good point about the 'break' statement. I can use that right now without really changing up my existing code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure this is a performance bottleneck before you begin over-optimizing?

One alternative is to keep the instances in an `NSMutableDictionary` where the key is an `NSNumber` of the `id`.  Then when you need to update a specific one, you can just retrieve the instance directly with `[myMutableDictionary objectForKey:@(someIntId)]`.  That would turn your O(n) loop into a O(1) hash table lookup [assuming a good `hash` implementation or it will be O(log n) in the worst case].

Comment: I don't think it is going to turn out to be a bottleneck issue as the array will probably hold less than 200 objects. I am trying to learn the best/correct way of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

There's two quick ways I see to optimize your code. First, you original assignment of your new object to replace the myClass instance in the array is unnecessary - since it's a pointer, you're actually directly manipulating the object in the array. Secondly, were you to retain your current for loop with an incrementer the original allocation of MyClass is unnecessary. You don't need to do alloc and init on it, because you only would need a pointer. However, you could use a for in loop rather than an incrementing for loop and just loop directly through the array.

Final code:

```
for (MyClass *myClass in myMutableArray)
{
    if(myClass.id == 5)
    {
        myClass.valueA = 100;
        myClass.valueB = 200;
        myClass.valueC = 300;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, you never want to name a varibale `id` in Objective - C. `id` means pointer to any type, and it is a reserved keyword.

A better / more efficient way of doing this is called **fast enumeration**. Fast enumeration is a special way to iterate through each item in a list/array/set. The code looks like this:

```
for (MyClass *iteratorObject in myMutableArray) {
    if (iteratorObject.id == 5) {
        //do what you want with that specific object
        //insert your modified object back into mutable array
    }
```

Although this would be the easiest way to do it, you are breaking one rule. You are never supposed to edit / add to / remove objects while performing fast enumeration on an array. My solution would be to simply call `[myMutableArray copy]` which return an immutableArray and then iterate through that.