# change the value of the key in NSMutableArray in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray

I have array like as follow:

```
(
  {
    id = 4;
    name = "AAAA";
  },

  {
    id = 5;
    name = "BBBB";
   },
 {  
    id = 9;
    name = "BBBB";
   }
)
```

How can I change the name where the id=5?

Comment: `array[1][@"name"] = @"CCCCC";`, is reading an introductory guide and/or the official docs so hard?

Comment: This is a horrid data structure.  You should just have a root dictionary instead.  Otherwise, you have to go through each element in the array and look for the one whose id is 5 and then change it.

Comment: Also, this question has ***nothing on Earth*** to do with Xcode. At all.

Comment: @H2CO3, Thanks for your reply... But i can't able to fetch the index of the array. I just have the id.

Comment: @user2526811 please don't use bold font to post your question/comment. Use bold only when it is needed, to **emphasize something**

Comment: Remarkably similar to [Finding a particular instance in an array by a property](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17867248) from earlier today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this.

Assume your array is called `array` and yourNewNameString is your new value for `name`

```
for(NSMutableDictionary *dict in array){
    if([[dict objectForKey:@"id"]integerValue]==5){
        [dict setObject:yourNewNameString forKey@"name"];
    }
}
```

**edit**
This is assuming you initialized your array with `NSMutableDictionarys` (Not just `NSDictionarys`)

Comment: **Thanks for reply..** _Wait i am trying your code._

Comment: yes,your code is right. But when i am try to scroll the table view then it will also change the name of other object.

Comment: cannot say anything unless i see some code mate

Answer (score 1):

```
    suppose Array = (
      {
        id = 4;
        name = "AAAA";
      },

      {
        id = 5;
        name = "BBBB";
       },
     {  
        id = 9;
        name = "BBBB";
       }
    )

    //Now to change the name where the id=5

    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [array objectAtIndex: 1];
    [dict setObject :@"hari kishan" forKey:@"name'];//this will change the name where id = 5
//Or if want to make dynamic

-(void)changeNameForId:(NSString*)id
{
for(NSMutableDictionary *dictionary in array)
{
    if([[dictionary objectForKey:@"id" isEqualToString :id]){
        [dictionary setObject:@"hari kishan" forKey@"name"]
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You are comparing the `integerValue` to the `NSString` id.  Not good.  -1

Comment: updated the answer:(thanks for notfying)

Comment: Alright, I removed the downvote because of your edit!